# select month in date with substring and cast in postgresql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, casting, substring

I've been cracking my head with this excercise, the professor want us to select only the months from a date type in postgresql, but using only substring and cast.
I've tried several ways, but none of them worked. This is the latter sentence that i have:

```
select substring(cast(fac.fecha as varchar(10)), '_____[0,9]___' ) from facturas fac
```

this sentence returns this:
[sentence result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKAti.png)

Comment: You will have better return if you add a http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[0,9]` is regex for "a single 0 or nine or colon".
You probably want `[0-9]{2}`, i.e. regex for "2 digits".

On the other hand, all implementations (those I know of) of `substr()` (different spelling, maybe you have a more powerful engine, which supports regexes...) use indexes into the string as parameters, nothing wiht regexes or even the single letter wildcards `_`.
So I recommend to study the documentation of your `substring()`.

Comment: You are quite right sir, the solution was the use of 6,2 as indexes:
select SUBSTRING(CAST(fac.fecha AS VARCHAR(10)), 6, 2) from facturas fac
Thank you a lot!